# $_POST/$_REQUEST Variables not being set in PHP/Codeigniter/Apache

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, post

First, on a local install of XAMPP, this works perfectly well. However, on an external (WAMP) server, it does not.

```
class Authentication extends MY_Controller {    
    function Authentication () {
        parent::__construct (FALSE);
        $this->template->set_template('authentication');
    }

    /**
     * Allows the user to log in to the system
     */
    public function index () {
        $person = $this->session->userdata("person");
        if (AUTHENTICATION_DISABLED || !empty($person)) {
            redirect('');
        }

        // if the user isn't already logged in, then they require a login page.
        $this->session->set_userdata("login_attempt", $this->session->userdata("login_attempt") + 1);

        $this->form_validation->set_rules("username", "User name", "required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password", "required");

        if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) {
            $this->load->model("person_model");

            $person = $this->person_model->get_person($this->input->post("username"));

            if ($person) {
                $this->session->set_userdata("person", $person);
                redirect('');
            }

        }

        if ($this->session->userdata("login_attempt") > MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS && !DISABLE_LOGIN_LIMIT) {
            $this->log('User locked out', __FILE__, __LINE__, Array (
                'login_attempts' => $this->session->userdata('login_attempt'),
                'lockout_time' => FAILED_ACCESS_LOCKOUT_TIME
            ));

            $this->session->sess_expiration = FAILED_ACCESS_LOCKOUT_TIME; // lock the user out for the amount of time specified in the config

            $this->data['max_login_attempts'] = MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS;
            $this->data['lockout_time_mins'] = FAILED_ACCESS_LOCKOUT_TIME / 60;
            $this->data['try_again_time'] = date('H:i', strtotime('+' . ($this->data['lockout_time_mins'] + 1) . ' minutes'));

            $this->template->write('title', 'Connection refused');
            $this->template->write_view('content', 'authentication/refused', $this->data);

            $this->template->render();
        } else {        
            $this->template->write('title', 'Log In');
            $this->template->write_view('content', 'authentication/login');

            $this->template->render();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Allows a user to log out of the system
     */
    public function logout () {
        if ($this->session->userdata('user_id') || DONT_REQUIRE_USER_ID) {
            $this->session->sess_destroy();

            $this->template->write('title', 'Logged Out');
            $this->template->write_view('content', 'authentication/logout');
            $this->template->render();
        } else {
            $this->log('Unauthorised access of logout page', __FILE__, __LINE__);

            show_404();
        }
    }
}
```

The form is simple ...

```
<form method="post" action="<?= site_url('authentication') ?>">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" />

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" />

    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

The POST variables are also being sent according to Firebug, but if I should put in something like

```
die(print_r($_POST, TRUE))
```

It just gives a blank "Array ()". Any ideas? Cos I'm fresh outta 'em :)

**Additional Stuff**
Incidentally, on non-related pages the server has been returning the correct content, but with a 404 header for some reason. I've bodged it to work, but I dunno - maybe it's a blatantly obvious problem I'm missing. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been a silly fool. It's rather important to add in:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

to httpd.conf in Apache if you're planning on using it! ;)

Lesson of the day - don't assume things are set up on another computer just because you've set it up on your own one ...

Answer (score 1):

Does it still happen if you use the `form` helper?

To use it:

In the controller add:
`$this->load->helper('form');`

And in your template, instead of:

`<form method="post" action="<?= site_url('authentication') ?>">`

write

`<?=form_open('authentication')?>`

Comment: What would that change?

Comment: Heya Paulina - thanks for responding to my cries for help :) I've tried it on the offchance, but it doesn't do a great deal unfortunately. My suspicion is that there's *something* going wrong on at the server, but that's an area I'm not vastly knowledgeable on! I may well be entirely wrong ...

Comment: @Shomz - codeigniter uses a crsf protection with the forms, so there was a slight chance that something was not working because the crsf token was not present. When using `form_open` codeigniter automatically adds an `input hidden` to the form with the crsf token.

@AlgyTaylor - since everything works on your local server, it seems like there is something wrong with the external server as you said. I'm assuming you have all paths in the `config.php` file set up correctly?

Comment: @paulina - Didn't know that about form_open at all, thanks - learnt something new already, and it ain't even 9am! ;)

Yeah, all the paths in the config file are correct as far as I can see ...